# Is it possible to run Protractor Test Suites in Parallel?

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor

I have protractor config file :

```
exports.config = {
  suites: {
    BVT : 'e2e/TestSuites/_BVT/*.js',
    Full : 'e2e/TestSuites/Full/**/*.js',
    Smoke : 'e2e/TestSuites/Smoke/*.js',
        Login1 : 'e2e/TestSuites/Login/*.js'
            };
  capabilities: {
     'browserName': 'chrome',
     shardTestFiles: true,
     maxInstances: 3
      };
};
```

I have tried above but my Test Suite doe not run in parallel, is it possible to run BVT, Full and Smoke Test suites in parallel on chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes possible for sure. Take a look how i am running regression and sanity in the suites.

```
protractor Test/config.js --suites regression,sanity
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error when I try running test from VSCode: 
`logger.js:158
[10:05:59] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 12
logger.js:158
[10:05:59] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
logger.js:158
[10:05:59] I/launcher - chrome #01-0 failed with exit code: 12
logger.js:158
[10:05:59] I/launcher - chrome #01-1 failed with exit code: 12
logger.js:158
[10:05:59] I/launcher - overall: 2 process(es) failed to complete
logger.js:158
[10:05:59] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100`

Comment: can you update the question with what you have changed?

Comment: updated question. If I run test using npm commandline `npm run e2e -- --suite=BVT,Smoke,Login1` it works but not from VSCode debugging.

Comment: @ssharma please refer the terminal in screenshot. You are invoking wrongly. cmd is `--suites regression,sanity`

Comment: `npm run e2e -- --suite=BVT,Smoke,Login1` command runs perfectly fine I am only having issue to run test in parallel from VSCode debugger.