# Protractor - How to run particular suite at run time & run all suites with common command?

Tags: angular, protractor

Protractor version: 5.4.1
Angular 8 based web application

1) I want to include the suites name at run time rather than defining in **package.json**. So, i will get flexibility to run any suite without the need of add all suites commands in the package file which is polluting. Example From the example I want to run only **group2** without defining as separate item in **package.json**. My Current command for particular suite is something like below in **package.json** file.

```
"view-group2": " \"ng e2e --dev-server-target= --no-webdriver-update --protractor-config=\"./test/config/view-suites.conf.js\" --suite group2\"",
```

I am getting the below error when tried to execute in command prompt/powershell. I tried with and without quotes but not success.

An unhandled exception occurred: Project 'group2' does not support the 'e2e' target.
See "C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ryByPU\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! tts@8.3.0 ng: `ng "e2e" "forex"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tts@8.3.0 ng script.

2) Inside suites, I have more than one suite group (example below). Is there any command available to run all suites rather than calling each one as comma separated? In some blogs it has been given as "--suites" but which is not supported. Even protractor document doesn't have any details on this option.

```
...    
suites:{
    group1:'../group1/*.spec.ts',
    group2:'../group2/*.spec.ts',
    ....
    ....
    groupn:'../groupn/*.spec.ts',
},
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60574114/8903949

Comment: Dear Bharath kumar, not directly for my second question, passing ``` --suites regression,sanity ``` will definitely help to run. My main requirement or need is to I have Suites file it will have multiple suite definition and more suites will be added as development in progress. Azure CI will be triggering the suites from background. Now I end up with adding new suite in Azure for every update which leads to more work.

If I can have a common command which can add all suites in that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the solution for my first requirement. So thought of sharing

> I want to include the suites name at run time rather than defining in package.json

The following code will help to add the suite name dynamically

```
@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --no-webdriver-update --port 4200
--protractor-config=test/config/view-suites.conf.js --suite %Suite%" --success first
```

Details of the commends below:-
**concurrently**  - is the nom library help to run script in parallel which required to be installed at global scope first
**Start-mock-server** - is the package.json based command for start mock server based the configuration
**node --max_old_space_size=4096** - is an optional parameter which require if your application package returns any heap memory issues, else this can be ignored
**%Suite%** - value will be dynamically password from Build definition. When run from developer machine this can be directly passed  as **—suite Login**. (*Login is example suite you defined in view-suites.conf.js file*)

This helped us not to pollute the package.json and also simply re-use the one build definition for different suites in Azure DevOps CI. Obviously dynamic value support is there in all Continuous Integration systems.